# Find' was of type 'int', which does not match the property type of 'long'

Tags: ef-core-2.0

Entity.

[Table("OrderLines", Schema = "Sales")]

> ```
>     public class OrderLine
>     {
>         [Key]
>         public long OrderLineID { get; set; }
>     }
> ```

Try to get entity by ID

```
public virtual async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(object id)
{
    if (id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Identifier is null");
    return await _entities.FindAsync(id);
}
```

Get an error 
System.AggregateException: "One or more errors occurred. (The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet.Find' was of type 'int', which does not match the property type of 'long'.)"

Comment: What's the question? Apparently you are passing `int` id to a function which expects `long` id.

Comment: you should explicitly cast the id to long when you want to use the method. like `GetByIdAsync((long)id)`

Comment: Why can't an int be implicitly converted to long?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got a resolution to this, but I came across the same issue and here was my issue and resolution.

I had a context that was scaffolded a long time ago and needed an update. Upon generating a new scaffolded context my method stopped working. What I discovered was that although all of the properties we present in both, the new context changed the order of `keys` in the modelBuilder.Entity for my table class.

So my method that stopped working was

```
if(await _ctx.MyTbl.FindAsync(a,b,c))
    DoSomething();
```

*Sidenote: My table is a db2 table with 3 primary keys*

My old modelBuilder.Entity looked like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MarketingRepresentativeAssignmentHistory_Ta00178>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { a, b, c }).HasName("MyKey");
}
```

My new one looked like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MarketingRepresentativeAssignmentHistory_Ta00178>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { b, a, c }).HasName("MyKey");
}
```

The issue was that `a` was of type DateTime and `b` was of type string.

By changing the order in the new context, the param were now out of order and tried to pass the incorrect types to what the db was expecting.

In reality it now makes total sense as `FindAsync` is a method and parameters must be in order unless the param names are specified, but I didn't find anything that specifically mentioned that the order mattered.